# Why do these two integration methods yield the same answer?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

These two methods yield the same answer, but I am not sure why. I am not able to see the similarity between these two. Are these two methods related? Could someone answer with this example?

$$\boxed{\int_1^3(3x-2)dx}$$

---

**METHOD $1$**

$=\int_1^3(3x-2)dx$

$= 3\bigg|\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|^3_1-2|x|^3_1$

$=3\big(\frac92-\frac12\big)-2(3-1)$

$= 3(4)-2(2)$

$= 12-4$

$= 8$

---

**METHOD $2$**
Limit of a Sum
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\space h\{f(a)+f(a+h)+f(a+2h)+\cdots+f(a+(n-1)h)\}$$

***Step-I***
$a=1,b=3,f(x)=3x-2\\\\ n=\frac{b-a}{h}=\frac2h$

***Step-II***
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\space h\{1+(1+3h)+(1+6h)+\cdots+(1+3(n-1)h)\}$

***Step-III***
$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\space h\{\underbrace{(1+1+\cdots+1)}_{n\text{ times}}+3h(1+2+\cdots+(n-1))\}$

$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\space h\{n+3h\cdot\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\}$

***Step-IV***
$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\{hn+3h^2\cdot\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\}$

$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\{2+3h^2\cdot\frac{(\frac2h-1)\frac2h}{2}\}$

$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\{2+\frac{3h^2(\frac{2-h}{h})\frac2h}{2}\}$

$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\{2+\frac{3\cdot(2-h)\cdot2}{2}\}$

***Step-V***
$= \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\{2+3(2-h)\}$

Applying limits
$= 2+3(2-0)$

$= 2+6$

$= 8$

Comment: The whiteboard solution can be viewed as a definition of the Riemann integral. The notebook solution employs a theorem about Riemann integrals known as the power rule.

Comment: This is part of the fundamental theorem of calculus: Definite integrals (defined as a limit of sums, your Method 2) can be computed using antiderivatives (your Method 1).

Comment: @Andreas Blass How are those methods related to each other?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax that I think you will find handy.

Comment: @Cognoscenti As I said, the relationship is part of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: The question itself is a phrased in an unusual way: In general, if two "methods" were to give _different_ answers, then at least one of them would not be a valid "method."

Comment: @Andreas Blass Yeah, so write an answer explaining the example in the question.